# Error in xj[i] : invalid subscript type 'list' in R

Tags: r

I am working with diabetes dataset.I am trying to fit the ‘best’ model obtained from my previous assignment on the training set and report the test error for this model.The code is below

```
library(nclSLR)
library(leaps)
library(glmnet)
data(diabetes)
set.seed(1)
(n = nrow(diabetes))
(p = ncol(diabetes) - 1)

train = diabetes [1:350,]
test = diabetes [351:442,]

grid=10^seq(10,-2,length=100)


best.subset=c("sex", "bmi", "map", "tc", "ldl", "ltg")

diabetes = diabetes[,best.subset]


#Train lm model
lm.mod=lm(sex~., diabetes[train,])
```

I am getting error in the last line. It shows

```
Error in xj[i] : invalid subscript type 'list'.
```

I have tried to unlist() but still not working.

Comment: The `train` is a `data.frame` and you are using that as index to subset `data.frame`.  Instead you may need `diabetes[1:350,]` or just `train` instead of `diabetes[train,]`

Comment: @akrun train instead of diabetes[train,] worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that we used the `i` i.e. row index as a data.frame.  Here, we need the subset of data.frame that is already created i.e. 'train'

```
lm.mod=lm(sex~., train)
```